# Desktop Search Tool with Lotus Notes Integration

Tags: search, ibm

Hey Fellow Ubuntu lovers,

I switched a while ago from Win. to Ubuntu and I am loving it! The only thing I miss is the desktop search integration with Lotus Notes. I've been searching the web for quite some while now but without any luck. To bad Google stopped because it seemed to be the only on supporting Lotus notes in Unix based environments.

Anyone got a hint or a tip?

Comment: What about Unity's global search ?

Answer (score 0):

IBM says Desktop Search for Linux is provided by Beagle Desktop and Tracker Desktop software

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.workplace.search85.googledesktop.doc%2Fp_search_m_ovr_srch_center.html

Comment: Hey Tom, this is the other way around "search from Lotus Notes in your PC". I want to do it the other way around :-) See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Ffram_what_new_85_r.html for the details

Comment: It looks like Beagle does exactly that. From your link: Searching your desktop from the search list in the tool bar is available on more operating systems ... Linux users: In the search field's drop-down list, click Beagle or Tracker and perform your search.

Answer (score -1):

There's a text search package called **recoll** available in the software center. It comes with Qt based gui.  If you also install the **recoll-lens** package you can do full text searches of docs directly from the Unity Dash.

Here's the recoll website: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/index.html
and here's a little article on the lens: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/recoll-lens-full-text-search-unity-lens.html

EDIT: Note that the recoll-lens is available through a separate ppa. To add it, type from the command line:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install recoll recoll-lens
```

Comment: Recoll has add-ins to index various file types, but it doesn't have an add-in for Notes/Domino NSF files.

Comment: My bad... Not that familiar with Notes